# Git responds with 'error in sideband demultiplexer'

Tags: git, corruption

I have two servers set up (as far as I know) exactly the same. On one of them, committing with git has always been fine, however on the second one, I've started getting this error:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: error in sideband demultiplexer

Everything is the same between the two, including the contents of the `.git/hooks/post-receive` file.

Is there a step in configuration I've missed somewhere, or something? I've tried reinitialising the repo twice now, to no avail.

My post-receive file is as follows:

> #!/bin/sh
>   cd ..
>   env -i git reset --hard

Comment: Added my post-receive file to the OP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On this [GitHub support thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017020019/http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2384-broken-repository-error-in-sideband-demultiplexer), this kind of error seems to be related to a [repository corruption](http://help.github.com/egit-corruption/) of some kind.

The issue was fixed by resetting the head of the corrupt remote repo (with [`git remote set-head`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)).

---

Update Nov. 2020, nine+ years later:

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the side-band status report can be sent at the same time as the primary payload multiplexed, but the demultiplexer on the receiving end incorrectly split a single status report into two, which has been corrected.

That could help avoid errors from the "remote end", as seen in the OP.

See [commit 712b037](https://github.com/git/git/commit/712b0377db60e0d3ac8bf3332022dfcd01e29afa) (27 Oct 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 8e86cf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e86cf6581655624e1f3284126c5ea664685eb44), [commit 17e7dbb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17e7dbbcbcee6912b00c815f4e800a3d38cd767c) (19 Oct 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6b9f509](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b9f5096eb034cc59a0a71b86ae65eb9433c8ea8), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sideband`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17e7dbbcbcee6912b00c815f4e800a3d38cd767c): avoid reporting incomplete sideband messages
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [2b695ecd74d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b695ecd74d174e23ed09c1c044f1313de538d15) (t5500: count objects through stderr, not trace, 2020-05-06) we tried to ensure that the "`Total 3`" message could be grepped in Git's output, even if it sometimes got chopped up into multiple lines in the trace machinery.
>
> However, the first instance where this mattered now goes through the sideband machinery, where it is *still* possible for messages to get chopped up: it *is* possible for the standard error stream to be sent byte-for-byte and hence it can be easily interrupted.
> Meaning: it is possible for the single line that we're looking for to be chopped up into multiple sideband packets, with a primary packet being delivered between them.
>
> This seems to happen occasionally in the `vs-test` part of our CI builds, i.e. with binaries built using Visual C, but not when building with GCC or clang; The symptom is that `t5500.43` fails to find a line matching `remote: Total 3` in the `log` file, which ends in something along these lines:
>
> ```
> remote: Tota
> remote: l 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
> ```
>
> This should not happen, though: we have code in `demultiplex_sideband()` *specifically* to stitch back together lines that were delivered in separate sideband packets.
>
> However, this stitching was broken in a subtle way in [fbd76cd450](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbd76cd450e6675cbd5d48da3c53fa446b776475) ("`sideband`: reverse its dependency on pkt-line", 2019-01-16, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f8b86db94e789bc07258f98cc5ba25d18273d83) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8feddda32cc50e928404788d7b9377c0b5f73f50)): before that change, incomplete sideband lines would not be flushed upon receiving a primary packet, but after that patch, they would be.
>
> The subtleness of this bug comes from the fact that it is easy to get confused by the ambiguous meaning of the `break` keyword: after writing the primary packet contents, the `break;` in the original version of `recv_sideband()` does *not* break out of the `while` loop, but instead only ends the `switch` case:
>
> ```
> while (!retval) {
>   [...]
>   switch (band) {
>       [...]
>   case 1:
>     /* Write the contents of the primary packet */>     write_or_die(out, buf + 1, len);
>     /* Here, we do *not* break out of the loop, `retval` is unchanged */
>     break;
>     ...]
>   }  
>
>   if (outbuf.len) {
>     /* Write any remaining sideband messages lacking a trailing LF */
>     strbuf_addch(&outbuf, '\n');
>     xwrite(2, outbuf.buf, outbuf.len);
> }
> ```
>
> In contrast, after [fbd76cd450](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbd76cd450e6675cbd5d48da3c53fa446b776475) ("`sideband`: reverse its dependency on pkt-line", 2019-01-16, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f8b86db94e789bc07258f98cc5ba25d18273d83) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8feddda32cc50e928404788d7b9377c0b5f73f50)), the body of the `while` loop was extracted into `demultiplex_sideband()`, crucially `_including`_ the logic to write incomplete sideband messages:
>
> ```
> switch (band) {
> [...]
> case 1:
>   *sideband_type = SIDEBAND_PRIMARY;> /* This does not break out of the loop: the loop is in the caller */>     break;
> ...]
>   }  
>
> cleanup:
>   [...]
>   /* This logic is now no longer `_outside`_ the loop but `_inside`_ */
>   if (scratch->len) {
>       strbuf_addch(scratch, '\n');
>       xwrite(2, scratch->buf, scratch->len);
>   }
> ```
>
> The correct way to fix this is to return from `demultiplex_sideband()` early.
> The caller will then write out the contents of the primary packet and continue looping.
>
> The `scratch` buffer for incomplete sideband messages is owned by that caller, and will continue to accumulate the remainder(s) of those messages.
> The loop will only end once `demultiplex_sideband()` returned non-zero *and* did not indicate a primary packet, which is the case only when we hit the `cleanup:` path, in which we take care of flushing any unfinished sideband messages and release the `scratch` buffer.
>
> To ensure that this does not get broken again, we introduce a pair of subcommands of the `pkt-line` test helper that specifically chop up the sideband message and squeeze a primary packet into the middle.
>
> Final note: The other test case touched by [2b695ecd74d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b695ecd74d174e23ed09c1c044f1313de538d15) (t5500: count objects through stderr, not trace, 2020-05-06, Git v2.27.0-rc0) is not affected by this issue because the sideband machinery is not involved there.

Comment: @Qombat: sorry to read that. Can you try to bundle your first repo, copy the resulting file on the second server, clone it and see if the problem persist then? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601242/how-to-move-git-repositories-and-minimize-downtime/3602748#3602748)

Comment: It seems to only happen every so often. I can get commits in that don't give me that error, but sometimes they do. I tried using the -f flag when pushing, didn't help.

Comment: @Qombat: but it does apply only for one server, right? Which is why I suggested the bundle and clone of the same repo from the other server in case there is some kind of corruption on the current repo from the second server.

Comment: @VonC I tried that just now, but the error's still there. As a test I removed the ./git/hooks/post-receive file, and it committed flawlessly in all three test commits. I don't know what the issue is there, but the contents of that file are in the OP. =\

Comment: @Qombat: would you post-receive hook implies your remote repo (to which you push to) isn't a bare repo?

Comment: What's a bare repo? Mine's a client-server setup sort of thing, I use it for web deployment because I like the way Git works.

Comment: @Qombat: ok but it is always better to push to a bare repo, and then (through a hook) to go to your live repo, pull the latest commit.

Comment: @VonC: But why does one repo error and the other not? Everything works perfectly on the other one. =\ How would I set that sort of configuration up?

Comment: @Qombat: I suspect some processes could have an handle on some of the files you want to reset (while the first server, depending on ots activity, might not). Having 2 repos (one bare and one checked out) ensure that the bare repo is always coherent (even if the non-bare repo has some trouble). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542854/calling-git-pull-from-a-git-post-update-hook/3542926#3542926

Answer (score 5):

In your hook, you never read from stdin. So probably the solution of this question works for you, too: [Error in sideband demultiplexer with a git post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592908/error-in-sideband-demultiplexer-with-a-git-post-receive-hook)

Comment: Worked for me, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592908/error-in-sideband-demultiplexer-with-a-git-post-receive-hook

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue.
and for me, it was because of my post-receive python script.
if there is any error in my python script, then i get always the error message:

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: error in sideband demultiplexer

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when `git` is prevented from MMAPing memory (due to a limit on the process).

On 64-bit architecture, git will attempt to mmap 1G of memory, which is surprisingly large and may cause issues if you're using `ulimit` (or `chpst` / `softlimit`) to control processes.

Removing the memory limit fixes things (for me).

Comment: Since I ruled out everything else, I think this could be my case. Could you please elaborate the fix a bit more on how to "remove the memory limit"? I've a non-upgradable 1 GB server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I pushed to an external web hosting service (heroku) and I interrupted the logging of the build process (by sleeping my laptop). The build from github to heroku succeeded without issue, but the logs were interrupted with the error message:

```
error in sideband demultiplexer
```

In my case it was nothing to worry about.