# Error in sideband demultiplexer with a git post-receive hook

Tags: git, apache, hook, githooks

I have set up one of my EC2 instances with git and using a post-receive hook I have it deploying to my server with [this tutorial](http://caiustheory.com/automatically-deploying-website-from-remote-git-repository).  This is the output from my console:

```
$ git push production master
git@example.com's password:
Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.51 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To git@184.169.147.123:halftown.git
   5d5e809..eb30e51  master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@example.com:git_application.git'
```

Please let me know if you need anything else to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git responds with 'error in sideband demultiplexer'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582849/git-responds-with-error-in-sideband-demultiplexer)

Comment: I originally thought it was a duplicate, however resetting the heads did not fix it.  Mine is a problem I believe is getting the hook to read the STDIN.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have figured out the problem that I was having.  Apparently, you have to make sure you read everything from STDIN before completing the script.

This was my post-receive hook before:

```
#!/bin/sh
git checkout -f
```

This is what I added that solved the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
:
done
git checkout -f
```

Comment: No matter what language you write your hook in just make sure that you read the STDIN first.