# git daemon clone is not working in local area network

Tags: git

I am using a local area network to access the files in my central repository.

#### System 1

I created a bare repository to store my files in it, I started a git daemon using the following command:

```
> git daemon --verbose --export-all --enable=upload-pack --enable=receive-pack --base-path=d:/
```

#### System 2

From the second system I am trying to clone the bare repository using the command

```
$ git clone git://192.168.1.8/bare-repository.git
```

But it gives the error like

```
$ git clone git://192.168.1.8/bare-repository
Cloning into 'bare-repository'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.R
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer`.
```

Can you please help me to solve that error?

Comment: Can you clone from the local machine? i.e. using `git://localhost/bare-repository.git`

Answer (score 2):

That type of error message is usually associated with:

- a connectivity issue (ie it does start the clone, but is unable to complete it because of connection glitch): see "[Git daemon cloning error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536729/6309)"
- a remote repo content issue: see "[Git responds with 'error in sideband demultiplexer'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582965/6309)"
- memory issue ([same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498654/6309))
- a post-receive hook ("[Error in sideband demultiplexer with a git post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9593585/6309)"), which shouldn't be the case here, as you are cloning, not pushing.