# git is unable to clone over LAN using `git daemon`

Tags: git, lan, git-clone, git-daemon

I have tried to clone my repo from another Windows PC over LAN.
Other post about `fatal: read error: Invalid argument` didn't give me any solutions.

### On the server

```
$ git daemon --base-path=/c/Users/user/Repos/ --export-all --timeout=10000 --port=9999 --verbose
[25784] Ready to rumble
[9248] Connection from 10.200.24.111:53464
[9248] unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE on socket: No error
[9248] Extended attribute "host": FLEXIT26015:9999
[9248] Request upload-pack for '/myrepo'
```

### On the client

```
$ git clone git://SERVERNAME:9999/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 38591, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (38591/38591), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16046/16046), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (38591/38591), 39.81 MiB | 6.99 MiB/s, done.
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
Resolving deltas: 100% (25978/25978), done.
fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

The server is not saying anything after the request?? Is this a git bug?
Please help! Maybe there is another way to clone my repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git responds with 'error in sideband demultiplexer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582849/git-responds-with-error-in-sideband-demultiplexer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+error+in+sideband+demultiplexer

Comment: Correct, it looks like the same issue but none of these answers solved my problem. In general, I think the git server is missing some good information... "Invalid argument" -> which argument?

Comment: @DrumM Did you found a solution? Have the same problem.